# AngularFire binding to scope vs $bindTo?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

In angular fire [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html), here are the two line I am trying to understand:

```
 // To make the data available in the DOM, assign it to $scope
     $scope.data = obj;

 // For three-way data bindings, bind it to the scope instead
     obj.$bindTo($scope, "data");
```

Are they doing the same thing? Do both bind to scope for 3 way data binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, they're not doing the same thing. That would be a pretty silly API. :-)

Running `$scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref)` binds the data in the Firebase location to the scope. Any update to the data in the Firebase database, will automatically be reflected in the scope and thus - if you bind an HTML element to `$scope.data` - also be updated on screen. The flow is uni-directional: from the database, to the screen.

Calling `obj.$bindTo($scope, "data")` both binds the data in the Firebase location to the scope *and* listens to changes to `$scope.data` that it then send back to the Firebase database automatically. So this creates a bi-directional, three-way binding. Updates in the HTML are sent to the database, updates to the database are sent to the screen.

This is all pretty well documented, for example in this blog post ["Three-Way Data Binding with Firebase and Angular"](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-04-firebase-angular-data-binding.html). The regular AngularFire documentation also contains a good section about [three-way data binding](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-objects.html#section-three-way-bindings).

Comment: Thanks Frank. got it now.